# javascript functionality with <script> and without <script>

Tags: javascript

This is the button event of html and it works when the button click

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

[Source of code 1](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_event_onclick1)

and this one work too but this time its function is written in  ***script***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>

<button onclick="displayDate()">The time is?</button>

<script>
function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

[Source code 2](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events1)

Both codes are giving the same result. Can we call both the codes are using javascript ? or codes are functional by using javascript functionality ? or javascript code is the only code in html page which is written inside *script*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes says it all (specially the part written in RED)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You can see yourself that both work so what's the question?

Comment: last two lines are my question , are both codes are using java script or we can only call that codes using javascript which are writes suing <script>

Comment: So you're asking if there's some other language used inline that looks exactly like JavaScript and acts exactly like JavaScript but has some other name?

Comment: No , i am saying only code which we write in <script> blocks are called javascript or we can use it directly without writing it in script , or is it compulsory to use script

Comment: You said *yourself* that both of them work, so isn't it *obvious* that you can use it "directly"! It works, doesn't it?

Comment: yes , but i am just beginner and start learning it , so i think it may be some sort of html functionality without javascript , cannt a beginner think like this ?

Comment: @ARG I don't know why everyone is being so hostile. If you look below I think I've answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No , i am saying only code which we write in  blocks are called javascript or we can use it directly without writing it in script , or is it compulsory to use script

It is not compulsory to write script, but it is a convention that is followed because you normally do not want your logic (Javascript) inside of your view (HTML).

If you look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) you'll see that onclick is a javascript handler for the click event.

## onclick

> The onclick property returns the click event handler code on the current element.

So both are javascript. The onclick tag specifies a way to write javascript without a script tag basically. Normally, however, you typically only put in a function call like in your first answer because of the reason above of separating logic and template.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes says it all:

> Every HTML element has a set of attributes that allow for the
>   execution of JavaScript when certain events happen. These attributes
>   are called **event attributes** and are the name of the event **prefixed by
>   "`on`"**.

here's a list of events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Each of this `on`prefixed events are collected by the HTML4 [DOM event interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and used by javascript in the `window` scope.

**[Avoid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes) such attributes.**
in short: keep your programmatic logic away from your template.
Use other [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to **attach event listeners** to your elements.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion both of the your approaches are using javascript. I prefer the second option and include the js from different file, but doesn't bother me if it's small project like this.